# is this a json.decoder error? what does this mean?

Tags: python, json

I keep getting this error for my python code here -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ragz/cowin.py", line 70, in <module>
    vaccine_check()
  File "/Users/ragz/cowin.py", line 43, in vaccine_check
    data = json.load(file)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
```

I am creating a python script that utilizes the COWIN api (for the Indian Government COVID Vaccine distributions) and the twilio whatsapp api to inform me about any updates on vaccine availability - heres my code -

```
from cowin_api import CoWinAPI
import json
import datetime
import numpy as np 
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import io
import requests
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from threading import Thread

state_id = '21'

district_id = '395'

min_age_limit = 18

time = datetime.datetime.now()

cowin = CoWinAPI()


def vaccine_check():

    try:
        available_centers = cowin.get_availability_by_district(district_id)

    #outputing it to a json file and bringing it back

        json_output = json.dumps(available_centers, indent=4)

        f = open(f'tests/vaccinecheck[{time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H|%M")}].json', 'a')

        f.write(json_output)
        f.close()

        with open(f.name) as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        n = np.arange(100)

        for x in np.nditer(n): 

            if data["centers"][x]["sessions"][0]["min_age_limit"] == 45:
                print('')   
            else:
                print(f'[{time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M")}]', data["centers"][x]["name"], '-- vaccines:', data["centers"][x]["sessions"][0]['available_capacity'], '-- age-limit:', data["centers"][x]["sessions"][0]["min_age_limit"])
                if data["centers"][x]["sessions"][0]["available_capacity"] >= 1:
                    twilio_send()
    except IndexError: # catch the error
        pass # pass will basically ignore it

def twilio_send():

    client = Client()

    from_whatsapp_number='whatsapp:TWILIO NUMBER'
        
    to_whatsapp_number='whatsapp:PHONE NUMBER GOES HERE'

    client.messages.create(body='VACCINE AVAILABLE!',
                       from_=from_whatsapp_number,
                       to=to_whatsapp_number)

vaccine_check()
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? I am also wondering if there is a way to loop it infinitely, if anyone knows.

Comment: the code is irrelevant. Extra data means that there's something after the valid json stream (that you didn't show)

Comment: what's the content of available_centers?

Comment: @aSaffary the content is just json data of  the available hospitals around me.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm sorry... not following?? pretty new to python and json.

Comment: Basically, assume this json: `{"test":5}`. You have valid JSON, but then have something after it, like this: `{"test:5}hello` or `{"test":5}{"x":true}` (missing comma) @trashflutterdev

Comment: why are you dumping the file then read the data again in the same program? this is useless

Comment: because I want to have a copy of the file later on. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: okay then don't read the file back. Just do `data = available_centers` because it's exactly the same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is wrong (mode `a`):

```
f = open(f'tests/vaccinecheck[{time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H|%M")}].json', 'a')
```

*you can't append to a json file without making the content non-json*

Either edit the content of the file or save it as a new json every time.

Note: you can use `json.dump` instead of `file.write` and `json.dumps`.

Comment: umm so what should I change?

Comment: @trashflutterdev change the 'a' in your open to 'w'. and depending on the content of your response you might need to declare encoding as 'utf-8'.

Comment: hey - i also tried infinitely looping it - it returned a different error - would you know how to do that..? im sorry for being a bother by the way... this is just really fun to write :)

Comment: @trashflutterdev you need to update your question with new code and error, also an example of your saved json file content.

Comment: can i just create a new question and give you the link????

Comment: @trashflutterdev if this problem is solved, accept the given answer and post a new one. otherwise just add more details to this question.